# How to track a pressure sensor from analog inputs?

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, pressure

I am a beginner with arduino. I have been researching pressure sensors composed of 2 conductors that sandwich a layer of velostat. My understanding is the velostat when compressed creates resistance between the conductive plates meaning when stepped on the charge decreases. I wanted to inquire about a wiring scheme for connecting these sensors to my analog inputs of a arduino nano with ideally 8 sensors connected to the 8 analog inputs. What is the wiring scheme? I would like to detect a gradation in sensitivity as best as possible for tracking someone applying pressure to that sensor. I have not built the sensors yet so that aspect of the project is open ended. Thanks for your attention in the matter. I am new to the world of electronics so please explain in elementary terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear, what exactly is your question here.

You are correct: The resistance of the velostat goes down, as pressure is applied to it. You have to build a voltage divider with the sensor and a normal resistor. The best value for that resistor highly depends on the sensor you build, because the way and the size you build it will control it's resistance. Then you can feed the middle pin of that voltage divider to an analog input.

The precision depends on many factors, including the sensor itself and the noise, that gets introduced into the analog input. Try and tweak your circuit, until it suits your needs.

Comment: What exactly is a voltage divider?

Comment: Two resistors in series, often (and also in this case) one of it with a variable resistance. One side connected to the supply voltage, the other side to ground. Then the voltage at the point between these resistors depends directly on the ratio of the resistors values. This is often used for analog measurement. For further explanation google voltage divider. There are many tutorials and sites on the web, that explain this perfectly.